# renumbering in a column when adding a row sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

For a table like

```sql
create table Stations_in_route
(
ID_station_in_route int primary key,
ID_route int,
ID_station int,
Number_in_route int not null
)
```

There is the following trigger that changes the values ​​in the Number_in_route column after a new row is added to the route. The list of numbers in the route must remain consistent.

```sql
create trigger stations_in_route_after_insert on Stations_in_route
after insert
as

if exists
(select *from Stations_in_route
where Stations_in_route.ID_station_in_route not in (select ID_station_in_route from inserted)
and Stations_in_route.ID_route in (select ID_route from inserted) 
and Stations_in_route.Number_in_route in (select Number_in_route from inserted))

begin
update Stations_in_route
set Number_in_route = Number_in_route + 1
where Stations_in_route.ID_station_in_route not in (select ID_station_in_route from inserted)
and Stations_in_route.ID_route in (select ID_route from inserted) 
and Stations_in_route.Number_in_route >= (select Number_in_route from inserted where Stations_in_route.ID_route = inserted.ID_route)
end
```

this trigger will throw an error if insertion into one ID_route is performed:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

For example,

```sql
Insert into Stations_in_route values(25, 4, 11, 3),(26, 4, 10, 5)
```

How to fix?

| ID_station_in_route | ID_route | ID_station | Number_in_route |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 4 | 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 4 | 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 4 | 8 | 8 |

i expect the list after adding will become like this

| ID_station_in_route | ID_route | ID_station | Number_in_route |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 25 | 4 | 11 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 |
| 26 | 4 | 10 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 4 | 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 4 | 6 | 8 |
| 7 | 4 | 7 | 9 |
| 8 | 4 | 8 | 10 |

this is not the whole table, as there are other routes too

Comment: *"this trigger will throw an error"* and what is the error? If i run the above, i get no errors: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a67007dd7d8494c7d89a644f48dc255a)

Comment: @Larnu
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
i.e. it doesn't work when added to the same route

Comment: That would be due to final clause in your `WHERE` in the trigger; that query can only return a scalar value. Again, however, the SQL you have given us does not product that error.

Comment: @AaronBertrand
I added an example.
I think that I will stop adding duplicates. I will roll back the update.

Comment: Still unclear what would happen if both new rows were given the same spot (e.g. 3), does something else force one of them to win? Also, in general, it may make more sense and for a much, much, much simpler trigger if you restrict inserts to single-row, then the logic is just `number_in_route + 1 where number_in_route > new_number_in_route`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the requirements, when you add new stops to the route, you need to insert them into their desired sequence correctly, and push all existing stops from that point forward so that a contiguous sequence is maintained. When you insert one row this isn't very hard (just `number_in_route + 1 where number_in_route > new_number_in_route`), but when you insert more rows, you need to basically push the entire set of subsequent stops by 1 for *each* new row. To illustrate, let's say you start with this:

> [image]

If we insert two new rows, such as:

```
INSERT dbo.Stations_in_route
(
  ID_station_in_route,
  ID_route,
  ID_station,
  Number_in_route
)
VALUES (25, 4, 11, 3),(26, 4, 10, 5);
-- add a stop at 3 ^              ^
----------------- add a stop at 5 ^
```

We can illustrate this by slowing it down into separate steps. First, we need to add this row at position #3:

> [image]

And we do this by pushing all the rows > 3 down by 1:

> [image]

But now when we add this row at position #5:

> [image]

That's the *new* position #5, *after* the previous shift, so it looks like this:

> [image]

We can do this with the following trigger, which is possibly a little more complicated than it has to be, but is better IMHO than tedious loops which might otherwise be required.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_ins_Stations_in_route ON dbo.Stations_in_route
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH x AS 
    (
      SELECT priority = 1, *, offset = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY ID_route ORDER BY Number_in_route)
      FROM inserted AS i
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT priority = 2, s.*, offset = NULL FROM dbo.Stations_in_route AS s
        WHERE s.ID_route IN (SELECT ID_route FROM inserted)
    ), 
    y AS 
    (
      SELECT *, rough_rank = Number_in_route 
          + COALESCE(MAX(offset) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Route 
            ORDER BY Number_in_route ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),0) 
          - COALESCE(offset, 0),
        tie_break = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (PARTITION BY ID_route, ID_station_in_route ORDER BY priority)
      FROM x
    ),
    z AS 
    (
      SELECT *, new_Number_in_route = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY ID_Route ORDER BY rough_rank, priority) 
      FROM y WHERE tie_break = 1
    )
    UPDATE s SET s.Number_in_route = z.new_Number_in_route
      FROM dbo.Stations_in_route AS s
      INNER JOIN z ON s.ID_route = z.ID_route
        AND s.ID_station_in_route = z.ID_station_in_route;
END
```

- Working example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f726ea09365ac8756abbda23ca735dc1)

I've mentioned a couple of times that you might want to handle ties for new rows, e.g. if the insert happened to be:

```
Insert into Stations_in_route values(25, 4, 11, 3),(26, 4, 10, 3)
```

For that you can add additional tie-breaking criteria to this clause:

```
  new_Number_in_route = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY ID_Route ORDER BY rough_rank, priority)
```

e.g.:

```
  new_Number_in_route = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY ID_Route ORDER BY rough_rank, priority, 
     ID_station_in_route DESC)
```

Comment: with such a trigger, I have a duplicate line with the number 6 (plus it rises to the 6th position instead of 5)
and the inserted records must fit in the proper positions and at the same time the order in the list must be preserved

Comment: @1i10 Please try again.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is working as expected. But it will take me a while to understand it. Seems complicated)

Comment: @1i10 Yes, because your requirements are complicated. :-) Honestly like I said above it would be far simpler if you forced one new stop at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to repro the exception with the test code/data in the question, however I'm gonna guess that the issue is with this bit of the code in the trigger:

```
AND Stations_in_route.Number_in_route >= 
(
SELECT Number_in_route
FROM inserted
WHERE Stations_in_route.ID_route = inserted.ID_route
)
```

The engine there will implicitly expect that subquery on the right-side of the >= operator to return a scalar result (single row, single column result), however the inserted table is in fact, a table...which may contain multiple records (as would be the case in a multi-row insert/update/etc. type statement as outlined in your example). Given that the filter (i.e. WHERE clause) in that subquery isn't guaranteed to be unique (ID_route doesn't appear to be unique, and in your example you have an insert statement that actually inserts multiple rows with the same ID_route value), then it's certainly possible that query will return a non-scalar result.

To fix that, you'd need to adjust that subquery to guarantee a result of a scalar value (single row and single column).  You've guaranteed the single column already with the selector...now you need to add logic to guarantee a single result/record as well.  That could include one or more of the following (or possibly other things also):

- Wrap the selected Number_in_route column in an aggregate function (i.e. a MAX() perhaps?)
- Add a TOP 1 with an ORDER BY to get the record you want to compare with
- Add additional filters to the WHERE clause to ensure a single result is returned